# Ocaml using the GCD function from reading a file

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to find the greatest common divisor of two numbers in ocaml

my code is below

```
open Printf
let rec gcd a b =
  if b = 0 then a else gcd b (a mod b);;
let file = "text.txt"

let () =
  let ic = open_in file in
  try
    let line1 = input_line ic in
    let line2 = input_line ic in
    printf "%d \n" (gcd line1 line2);;
    flush stdout;               
    close_in ic                 
  with e ->                     
    close_in_noerr ic;          
    raise e
```

my text file would have for example

```
40
42
```

Why can't I use my function `gcd` after I open the file and get the lines?

Comment: input_line returns a string. Try using the int_of_string function.

Comment: @G4143 thanks for the suggestion! I haven't succeeded turning the string to an int. But even when I just use two random integers in the function, it wouldn't work.

Comment: If I extract the 2 lines above and paste into the OCaml toplevel, your `gcd` function works for me. For example `# gcd 88 14 ;;` => `- : int = 2`.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield it works but not inside ```let ()```. it doesn't work when I try to print it there.

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked for me with my correction.

Comment: You'll have to show the code that doesn't work. The above code is clearly wrong as @G4143 pointed out. So it won't even compile.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield It does? when I do ```printf "%d \n" (gcd 55, 200);;``` for example instead of ```printf "%d \n" (gcd line1 line2);;``` it gives me ```Error: Syntaxt error```

Comment: Note: I also replaced the ;;(the double semi-colon after the printf line) with a single semi-colon ;. You need the sequence operator here(the single semi-colon is the sequence operator).

Comment: @G4143 ah okay that was the problem, it was such a simple one. now I just have to convert the string to an int! I have been looking for the documentation and I have a question. how do i use the string_of_int function?

Comment: int_of_string (expression that returns a string). In your case let line1 = int_of_string(input_line ic)... line1 now contains an int if the string was a valid integer.